# CORS problem with QWebEngine: are there limitation regarding the possible `Origin` values?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, cors, qtwebengine

We maintain an application whose UI contains a `QWebEngineView`. The pages displayed in this view are taken from a local resource bundle, i.e. urls like qrc://mypage.html.

Some JS from the page does `window.fetch(https://some.thi.ng)` some url on Internet servers, with CORS enabled in the webview.

Everything was working fine with Qt 5.9.6. Yet, upgrading to Qt 5.12.1 introduced a CORS error:

> Failed to load https://some.thi.ng: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header has a value 'qrc://' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'qrc://' is therefore not allowed access.

Well, it seems that it complains *qrc://* is not equal to *qrc://*.

By using the webview chrome debugger, we could indeed confirm that the request sent an `Origin` header with value *qrc://*, and that the response did contain a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the same value.

By reading the [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), it seems that this is supposed to satisfy all criterions, and that the request should be conducted by the browser without any error.

Is it a problem that `qrc://` is not a valid origin? A bug with the updated Qt chromium engine?